# Basic probability question, confusion with basic concept

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

There is a bag with $95$ green and $5$ red balls. If $3$ balls are drawn, what is the probability that $2$ of them are red and $1$ green?

Solution 1:

Total number of ways is $100\choose3$

Favorable number of ways = $\binom{5} {2} * \binom{95}{1}$

So required probability = $\frac{\binom{5}{2} \binom{95}{1}}{\binom{100}{3}}$

Solution 2:
   However since the favorable number of ways is obtained by multiplying $5\choose2$ and $95\choose1$, it takes the order between two red and one green in to account while the total number of ways does not take order in to account. 
Should I therefore divide by $2$ to get the accurate favorable number of ways?
so required probability will be $\frac{\binom{5}{2} \binom{95}{1}}{\binom{100}{3}*2}$

Solution 3:

Total number of ways = $\binom{100}{3} * 3!$ (counting in way to account for order)

Favorable number of ways = $\left(\binom{5}{2} * 2!\right) * \left(\binom{95}{1} * 1!\right)$ (to also account for order like in denominator)

So required probability = $\frac{\binom{5}{2} * \binom{95}{1}}{\binom{100}{3} *3}$)

I understand that as long as we are consistent in taking in to account the order when counting favorable and total ways, we should get the same probability.
However I am finding it hard to reconcile solution 1 vs solution 2 vs solution 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

${^{100}\mathrm C_{3}}$ counts ways to select *three from one hundred* balls.   This does *not* count ways to arrange those selected items.

${^{5}\mathrm C_{2}}\cdot{^{95}\mathrm C_{1}}$ counts ways to select *two from five* red balls and *one from ninety-five* green balls.   Likewise this does **not** count ways to arrange those selected items.

Therefore the probability you seek is: $$\dfrac{{^{5}\mathrm C_{2}}\cdot{^{95}\mathrm C_{1}}}{{^{100}\mathrm C_{3}}}$$

---

Alternatively, consider the task as lining up the one hundred balls and selecting the first three.   We shall then count ways to select places for the red balls.

${^{3}\mathrm C_{2}}\cdot{^{97}\mathrm C_{1}}$ counts ways to select two among the first three places and one among the latter ninety-seven places, while ${^{100}\mathrm C_{5}}$ counts ways to select five among the one-hundred places .

Thus the probability we seek is: $$\dfrac{{^{3}\mathrm C_{2}}\cdot{^{97}\mathrm C_{3}}}{{^{100}\mathrm C_{5}}}~~=~~\dfrac{\tfrac{3!}{2!~1!}\cdot\tfrac{97!}{3!~94!}}{\tfrac{100!}{5!~95!}}~~=~~\dfrac{\tfrac{5!}{2!~3!}\cdot\tfrac{95!}{1!~94!}}{\tfrac{100!}{3!~97!}}~~=~~\dfrac{{^{5}\mathrm C_{2}}\cdot{^{95}\mathrm C_{1}}}{{^{100}\mathrm C_{3}}}$$

Comment: (...) counts ways to select two from five red balls and one* from ninety-five green balls (...)

Comment: In general when we multiply n1 and n2 in which event E1 and E2 happens, then product of n1 and n2 will take in to account the ordering between E1 and E2, if ordering is possible. For solution 2, when I multiply 52 and 951, then will it not take in to account the order between two red balls and one green ball? –

Comment: *If* you wanted the probability that the *first* two balls were red and the *third* was green, then you count the total in the same manner (selecting the first two and third); either by selecting 2 from 100 and 1 from the remaining 98, *or* selecting 2 from the 3 selected from 100.$$\def\C#1#2{\mathop{^{#1}\mathrm C_{#2}}} \dfrac{\C{5}{2}\C{95}{1}}{\C{100}{2}\C{98}1}~~=~~\dfrac{\C{5}{2}\C{95}{1}}{\C{100}{3}\C{3}2}$$

Answer (score 3):

Solution $1$ is correct.

Your statement under solution $2$ that multiplying $\binom{5}{2}$ by $\binom{95}{1}$ "takes order into account" is erroneous.  I don't understand why you say this.

In solution $3$, you've taken order into account properly in the denominator, but your attempt to do so in the numerator is flawed.  In order to take order into account, we say there are $3$ possible orders, RRG, RGR, GRR.  Each of these can occur in $5\cdot4\cdot95$ ways, so we get $$\frac{3\cdot5\cdot4\cdot95}{100\cdot99\cdot98}$$ for the probability, the same answer as in $1$.

The way you did it in solution $3$, you took the order in which the red balls are drawn into account, but not the order of the green ball in relation to the red balls.

Comment: In general when we multiply n1 and n2 in which event E1 and E2 happens, then product of n1 and n2 will take in to account the ordering between E1 and E2, if ordering is possible. For solution 2, when I multiply $5C2$ and $95C1$, then will it not take in to account the order between two red balls and one green ball?

Comment: No.  When you say there are  $_5C_2=\frac{5\cdot4}{2}$ ways to choose the red balls, you have already divided by $2$.  Besides, as I noted in the analysis of solution $3$, there are three actions, because you choose $3$ balls.  If you want to take order into account, you must consider all $3$ actions.

Comment: @rasdocus Flip a coin and roll a die. There are $6x2=12$ outcomes regardless of whether you imagine they are ordered or not, because the two sub-processes don't overlap (the answer isn't $6$ nor $24$, right?). Same with the red balls and green balls ( but NOT the same as picking $2$ red balls).

Comment: @Ned, I think I understand what you mean. When you say that the two sub-processes don't overlap, do you mean you cannot order them? what is your definition of non overlapping processes?

Comment: @rasdocus The point is that the die roll and the coin flip come from different sets. Unlike picking 2 balls from an urn, where each of the balls could be first or second, in this case only the coin can give H and only the die can give 3. So in the latter you don''t have to divide by 2, but in the former you do because you are doing the same thing twice in a row (i.e. picking a ball from the urn).

Comment: @Ned, so in this problem, even though we are picking red and green balls from the same urn, we are still picking two red from red balls and one green from green balls, they effectively act as two parallel processes? this is where I got confused.

Comment: @rasdocus I wouldn't put too much emphasis on the words -- natural language didn't evolve to be good at mathematical precision. Do you see why the dice/coin thing comes out to $6x2=12$? Can you apply that mental picture to see why the number [RRG] unordered combo's in your set-up is (# ways to pick two R)*(# ways to pick 1 G)? But that picking 2R's from 5 is different? That's what I would think about -- the mental picture -- rather than trying to come up with a pithy, precise wording.